# Why do we use typeof XMLHttpRequest !="undefined"? What it is undefined?

Tags: javascript

Why do we use `typeof XMLHttpRequest !="undefined"`?

What it is undefined i didn't understood what is undefined there?

```
 if (typeof XMLHttpRequest != "undefined")
     {
        xmlHttp= new XMLHttpRequest();
     }
     else if (window.ActiveXObject)
      {
        xmlHttp= new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }
```

Comment: RTFM - [undefined](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined), [typeof](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof)

Comment: *Old* IE (IE6, IE7?) versions did not have `window.XMLHttpRequest`, which is what the condition is testing for.

Comment: IMO, it's nicer to check globals as a property of `window`, like `if (window.XMLHttpRequest != undefined) {`. This avoids the ReferenceError.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, unless you have some extremely odd requirement to support IE6, remove this code.  It is no longer needed.

It is just checking to see if the symbol `XMLHttpRequest` is defined in the browser or not as a means of seeing whether this browser natively supports Ajax calls or not.

If not, it's falling back to a proprietary Microsoft implementation.  If `xmlHttpRequest` is defined, then `typeof XMLHttpRequest` would have a value of "function", not "undefined".

As an example:

```
var x = 3;

console.log(typeof x);    // "number"
console.log(typeof y);    // "undefined"

// And, in any modern browser
console.log(typeof XMLHttpRequest);  // "function"

// In IE6
console.log(typeof XMLHttpRequest);  // "undefined"
```

This type of check for the presence of `XMLHttpRequest` is for very old Microsoft browsers (IE6 and older) and is no longer needed and can be safely removed.

Comment: Thank you for all your replies your answers help me a lot

Answer (score 3):

These kinds of checks are for very old versions of Internet Explorer (IE6 and lower to be exact).

There are several ways to detect whether a browser supports `XMLHttpRequest`. Using `typeof SomeObject` is just one of the ways. You might also see...

```
if ("XMLHttpRequest" in window) { ... }
```

or just straight up

```
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { ... }
```

Comment: Your last one sort of misses the point of why `typeof` was used. You'll get a ReferenceError when it doesn't exist. You can use `window.XMLHttpRequest` instead.